# nginx remove if statements

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I am looking for a little advice here for a nginx noob.  I have been reading that if statements are way slow in nginx so I was hoping for a little help in converting these.  I have tried a bunch of different methods, all failures, so I thought I would toss up a question.

```
server_name *.noconformity.co noconformity.co;
# remove all sub domains and www
if ($http_host !~* "^(ftp|ssh)\.noconformity\.co$"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($http_host ~ "^([^.]+)\.noconformity\.co$"){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://noconformity.co/$1 permanent;
    break;
}
# Login Short Cut
if ($uri ~* "/login") {
    rewrite ^/login(/.*)? /wp-admin$1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely untested - quite likely to have mistakes - but hopefully the concept is valid.

The config below is based what I interpret your objective to be: redirect all subdomains, except 'ftp' and 'ssh' to the main site; Redirect /login to /wp-admin

Create a server block to accept connections to the ftp and ssh subdomains - and then do something here (like deny, or return 403, etc) - since this is a static server_name, it takes precedence over the wildcard server_name.

```
server {
    server_name ftp.noconformity.co ssh.noconformity.co;
    #additional options
}
```

Your main server block - add your rewrite to a location block

```
server{
    server_name noconformity.co;
    #root ....; 
    #your main config

    location ~* /login/ {
        rewrite ^/login/(.*)? /wp-admin$1;
    }
}
```

{I had to change the /login/ rewrite to avoid getting stuck in a loop with the built in WP log in redirect}

Finally, a wildcard server_name - this will match any subdomain (except those already matched) capture the path, and rewrite to your main site.

```
server {
    server_name *.noconformity.co;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://noconformity.co/$1 permanent;
}
```

The nginx [page on server_names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) is worth reading, as it explains the priority of different server_name expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The better answer to this question is using the [HTTP Map Module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule). Your example above is almost the same case use as what they have demonstrated. Much cleaner and easier to manage.